# How to create MSIL files from dll/exe

Tags: c#, mono

I have some .net dll's and Exe's.
I need to pass MSIL files to mono project.
How do i convert these Dll's to MSIL files?

Comment: MSIL is officially called CIL now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can view the IL from the DLL or EXE by running [ILDASM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7dy01k1%28VS.80%29.aspx). There's no conversion required.

Answer (score 1):

.NET dll's and exe's *are* MSIL files, so you do not need to convert anything.

You can use the .NET disassembler ([ildasm.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7dy01k1.aspx)) to see that this is indeed the case.

Comment: Actually, the content is compressed byte code which != MSIL. You still need to 'convert' it with ILDASM.