# When is MSIL generated?

Tags: cil

Let's say I have a C# Windows Class library in my solution and I build it in my VS2010 IDE.
The output here in my bin directory is X.dll

**1)** X.dll does not contain MSIL at this stage but "compressed byte code".
   Is this true?

**2)** This "compressed byte code" is converted to MSIL somehow.
   When does this occur?

**3)** When X.dll is accessed the JIT compiler of CLR takes the portion of MSIL that it needs to convert and does so into machine code.
Am I good on this final part?

Can anybody help in filling in the gaps in my understanding here?

Comment: +1 because I hadn't ever seen of "compressed byte code". I would think its relation to MSIL is like the relation of machine code to assembly language, right?

Comment: I've made some searches. I've found a single reference to compressed byte code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2665882/how-to-create-msil-files-from-dll-exe/2665891#2665891

Answer (score 2):

X.dll contains MSIL bytecode after you build it with Visual Studio. You can prove this by disassembling it with [ildasm](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7dy01k1).

At some time between assembly loading and the actual execution of the code, the MSIL is translated to native code. I am not familiar with where exactly this is done, but I would suspect at assembly load.

Comment: My application's exe file contains C# code. You can prove this by disassembling it with Reflector. :-P @xanatos missed the smiley?

Comment: @Codecaster Excuse me :-) Yes... It wouldn't ever be the strangest thing I ever read on SO :-)

Comment: @FuzzyFrog: Often you will hear them interchanged. When someone says MSIL, they may mean bytecode or they may mean the textual assembler-style representation. Bytecode is the compiled, machine-readable format.

Answer (score 0):

To build upon Dark Falcon's response, on question no.2, the IL code (not compressed byte code) is converted to native code by the JIT compiler, method by method, at each of their first call. So, a shorter answer for no.2 is "when the method is first accessed". Fields are not subject to this, properties are disguised methods themselves.

As for the third question, no, the IL is not JITed when it is loaded. See above.

Comment: It's jitted somewhere between the module being loaded and the method being called. The run-time typically tries to delay it as late as possible but there is no guarantee that it will be as late as first access, particularly when [constrained execution regions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228973%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [CriticalFinalizerObjects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.constrainedexecution.criticalfinalizerobject%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) are involved.